# OpenState API v1 returning no committees

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, jboss

I’m programmatically calling Open State API v1 for fetching the legislators data for the state, up-to last month I was getting the committees metadata with legislators response, but this month I’m not getting it.
On the Official doc its clearly mention that Committee endpoints are no longer supported in API V1, but still, I want to know is there any way to get the committees using OpenState API v1

Offical doc link:

http://docs.openstates.org/en/latest/api/legislators.html#legislators

The endpoint to get legislators with committees for the state

**GET HTTP:**

> openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/?state=dc&chamber=upper&apikey=xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx

Thanks in Advance